# Using <input type="url"> to handle both HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: html, forms

The URL input `<input type="url">` takes `pattern` attribute which allows us to specify a JavaScript regex to validate the input value.

In this MDN example, the pattern provided is `pattern="https://.*"` which expects an `https` protocol. This means a `http` value will not be accepted.

```
<label for="url">Enter an https:// URL:</label>

<input type="url" name="url" id="url"
       placeholder="https://example.com"
       pattern="https://.*" size="30"
       required>
```

Not all URLs are `HTTPS`, so is this option too strict?

In the documentation explaining the [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url#pattern), it says:

> If the specified pattern is not specified or is invalid, no regular
>   expression is applied and this attribute is ignored completely.

I thought this meant that if the pattern attribute is not included, then the value of `www.example.com` would be accepted. However, it seems like this is not the case.

Question:
How do we use the url input to flexible handle both `http` and `https` values? Moreover, it seems like it would be simpler if the user is able to simple enter `www.example.com` without specifying the protocol.

Comment: `I thought this meant that if the pattern attribute is not included, then the value of www.example.com would be accepted. However, it seems like this is not the case.` No, the value still must fit the URL pattern regardless of additional `pattern` criteria. Therefore it must start with a protocol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `?` to the pattern

```
pattern="https?://.*"
```

`?` makes `s` optional.

Comment: I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070841/pattern-in-html5-input-type-url-validation). i am wondering if you can have a look.