# pattern in html5 input type url validation

Tags: html, regex, validation

I have a **form** as shown below in which I want the **user** to enter the **url in the input box** starting from **http://** or **https://** with **one 
period** to be present after **subdomain**. If the user doesn't do so it should say **"Please match the requested format"**.

This is what I have tried. The following code takes only from https not http.

```
<label for="url">Enter an https:// URL:</label>

<input type="url" name="url" id="url" placeholder="https://example.com" pattern="https://.*" size="30" required>  <!-- Line A -->
```

The **pattern** which I want is:

1. https://example.com
2. http://example.com
3. https://www.example.com
4. http://www.example.com

In the first 2 cases, user doesn't type **www** in the input box and in the last 2 cases user types **www** In the above four urls, 
it has atleast **one period after subdomain** and it starts from **http** or **https**.

In short, I want the **following 2 requirements** to be met when user enters the **url in the input box**.

1. It should start from http or https.
2. It should have at-least one period after sub-domain.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the pattern above at Line A so that it meets my requirements.

Comment: What language are you using to process your form? PHP? CGI/Perl?

Comment: I am using php. I think we need to make some minor changes here `pattern="https://.*"` but I am not sure what it should be.

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58154804/8138584

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can probably use url validation segments after the http://

```
<input type="url" 
  name="url"
  id="url"
  placeholder="https://example.com"
  pattern="[Hh][Tt][Tt][Pp][Ss]?:\/\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?"
  required>
```

Expanded

```
 [Hh] [Tt] [Tt] [Pp] [Ss]? :\/\/
 (?:
      (?: [a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
      [a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
 )
 (?:
      \. 
      (?: [a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
      [a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
 )*
 (?:
      \. 
      (?: [a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,} )
 )
 (?: : \d{2,5} )?
 (?: \/ [^\s]* )?
```

Comment: hi, I have one issue coming up. It is meeting the boundary conditions which I have mentioned above. **1**. It should start from http or https. **2**. It should have at-least one period after sub-domain.
Thanks for that. When I enter **/** after the url https://facebook.com/ it is asking me to macth the requested format. I am wondering if you can remove this validation from the pattern. We want users to
enter **/** after .com .org .net .gov .in

Comment: Example, when I enter https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php it is asking me **Please match the requested format**.

Comment: Example, when I enter php.net/manual/en/function.date.php it is asking me **Please match the requested format**.


Basically after .com .net .gov user should have the ability to add **/**

In my condition, user definitely enter:

**1.** http or https (It should start from http or https)
**2.** It should have atleast one period after sub-domain

Comment: @flash - Add `(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?` at the end

Answer (score 6):

I think the pattern below should work for you:

```
http(s?)(:\/\/)((www.)?)(([^.]+)\.)?([a-zA-z0-9\-_]+)(.com|.net|.gov|.org|.in)(\/[^\s]*)?
```

You can see it working [here](https://regexr.com/4m9oo)

Comment: hi, I have one issue coming up. It is meeting the boundary conditions which I have mentioned above. **1**. It should start from http or https. **2**. It should have at-least one period after sub-domain.
Thanks for that. When I enter **/** after the url https://facebook.com/ it is asking me to macth the requested format. I am wondering if you can remove this validation from the pattern. We want users to
enter **/** after .com .org .net .gov .in

Comment: Example, when I enter php.net/manual/en/function.date.php it is asking me **Please match the requested format**.

Comment: Example, when I enter php.net/manual/en/function.date.php it is asking me **Please match the requested format**.


Basically after .com .net .gov user should have the ability to add **/**

In my condition, user definitely enter:

**1.** http or https (It should start from http or https)
**2.** It should have atleast one period after sub-domain

Comment: I have updated regex and it should match all your conditions now

Answer (score 4):

```
pattern="^(http(s)?:\/\/)+[\w\-\._~:\/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$"
```

criteria:
1. start from http or https
2. it can be consist of  subdomain

examples:
1. https://www.example.com
2. http://www.example.com
3. https://example.com
4. http://example.com
5. http://blog.example.com

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work if I understood your problem...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Url</title>
</head>
<body><form action="">
    <input type="url" pattern="https?://.+" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please match the requested format')" >
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The "pattern" attribute can have a regex expression for your input field.

Comment: I feel like this answer is very underrated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this may be the desired pattern?

```
<label for="url">Enter an https:// URL:</label>

<input type="url" name="url" id="url" placeholder="https://example.com" pattern="http(s?)(:\/\/)((www.)?)([a-zA-z0-9\-_]+)(.com)" size="30" required>
</body>
```

The pattern, explained:
**http**
**(s?)** followed by an optional **s** on the protocol
**(:\/\/)** the **://** between the protocol and the subdomain
**((www.)?)** optional **www.** subdomain
**([a-zA-z0-9\-_]+)** the second-level domain (the portion after the subdomain (if present) and before the .com) considering alphanumeric with hypens or underscores
**(.com)** the top-level domain (.com specific, in this example)

You can check the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/QRjkaw/4) too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regular expression there 
just an example ,

```
<label for="url">Enter an https:// URL:</label>

<input type="url" name="url" id="url" placeholder="https://example.com" 
 pattern="^(http|https)://\.(.*)" size="30" required>
```

Comment: Is it gonna meet all my requirements above ?

Answer (score 0):

escaped:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)?[\w\d]*\.([a-zA-Z]*\.)?([a-zA-Z]*)?$/
```

pure regex:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(wwww{1}\.)?[\w\d]*\.([a-zA-Z]*\.)?([a-zA-Z]*)?$
```

works well for me. tested in https://regex101.com/ for these cases:

```
http://test.com
https://www.test.com
http://www.test.com
https://test.com
www.test.com
```